# Why doesn't this work for me? c#

Tags: c#, class, datatable

I try to make a program so I can see how much I use of electricity, water, etc. per year. I've created three forms containing

1. MainForm
2. A form where I can add the data and
3. A setting for "MainForm"

On `MainForm` there is a `DataGridView` and in a class `loadlist.cs` I put in the code to load data from SQL Server using a `DataTable`.

Now I want form 2 to access the `loadlist.cs` and it works properly - I get a `MessageBox.Show()` result to check.

But when I want to it add the data to the `DataGridView`, it doesn't work.

How?

Code from "MainForm.cs":

```
Jojo op = new Jojo();

Gridview_index.DataSource = GetTable();
Gridview_index.DataSource = op.JojoGetir("Elforbrug");
```

Code from "loadlist.cs":

```
public List<GetValues> JojoGetir(string input) {
    AutoClosingMessageBox.Show(input, "Vis", 1000);

    List<GetValues> JojoListesi = new List<GetValues>();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + input;

    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        GetValues ogr = new GetValues();
        ogr.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr [0]);
        ogr.Dato = Convert.ToDateTime(dr [1].ToString());
        ogr.Aflæsning = Convert.ToInt32(dr [2]);
        ogr.Forskel = Convert.ToInt32(dr [3]);

        JojoListesi.Add(ogr);
    }

    con.Close();
    return JojoListesi;
}
```

Code from "add.cs":

```
if (Vaelgforbrug.SelectedItem != null && 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IndtastForbrug.Text) == false) {
    cmd.Connection = cn;

    cn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show((DateTime.Parse(datoForbrug.Value.ToShortDateString())).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into " + Vaelgforbrug.SelectedItem + "forbrug (Dato, Aflæsning, Forskel) VALUES ('" + (DateTime.Parse(datoForbrug.Value.ToShortDateString())).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "', '" + IndtastForbrug.Text + "','" + 0 + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    AutoClosingMessageBox.Show("Gemt!", "Opsætning", 1000);
    cn.Close();
    Close();

    var op = new Jojo();
    var f = new Forbrug();

    f.Gridview_index.DataSource = op.JojoGetir(Vaelgforbrug.SelectedItem + "forbrug");
}
```

From "AutoClosingMessageBox" I get the "input" where I can see it's triggered but no data is entered in "Gridview_index". It saves the data I want to add to SQL Server but not to Gridview_index.

Comment: Very first thing to do: stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead. You should fix that before you do *anything* else, so that by the time you've got to working code, you don't have a SQL injection attack. Rather than having multiple tables with the same structure, you may well want to have a single table with one value saying where it's a row representing water, electricity or gas.

Comment: Thank you, Jon Skeet. I'll change it to parameterized SQL when I make another version of this. If I understand you correctly you want a single table with all the information (Id, Date, Electricity, Gas, Water, numbers)? I thought it should be made the other way with multiple tables.

Comment: If you have a single table, you don't need to construct the SQL even for the table name. You can just add an extra field to say which kind of value it is, which simplifies things.

Comment: True - that makes sense to me. How do I then get the data from database through "add.cs" (as when INSERT is complete) to "MainForm.cs" datagridview? I can't figure out why it doesn't work though I get the messagebox with all the information. I must be missing something :-) :-)

Comment: That's an entirely different question - presumably you're not updating your datasource on the main form after performing the insert.